# Installing Ubuntu Server on AppleTV Gen1

Tags: boot, server, apple

I bought a used AppleTV with OSMC installed on it and I now want to install Ubuntu Server.

I created a bootable USB with rufus etc. but I can't get it to boot from USB. I tried every Key I know but it doesn't seem to do anything.

- What Key do I have to press on startup to get into the Bios of the AppleTV?
- Is there another way to install Ubuntu server on the AppleTV without the use of a bootable USB?

Comment: There is no BIOS to access. Connect the USB keyboard and USB device to the AppleTV, then reboot the Apple device and telnet in from your computer. The username and password are both `root`. From there, invest your entire weekend to getting the OS installed and configured, followed by a period of disappointment as you see that the AppleTV can’t support any *modern* version of Linux aside from Bodhi 